# Deletion of Opencart Featured Products Homepage Module

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I have accidently deleted opencart Featured Product Homepage module i-e 
 Featured > Home Page from the admin panel > Modules. 
 How to can I restore it?

Comment: Perhaps Server Fault (another site in the Stack Exchange network) is a better place for this question.

Comment: @PaulStelian the question is not asked by a server.

Comment: @AmitRay Servers can't ask questions :) Editing such a module is probably about some website, and Server Fault is better fit for dealing with website administration (of about any kind)

Comment: @AmitRay Also, besides websites what else has admin panels? I've seen nothing really.

Comment: @PaulStelian he said he **accidentally deleted** a module. If he has backup he can restore it.

Comment: Well, anyway opencart is a website framework. Thus my suggestion to move to Server Fault. @AmitRay.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Actually i deleted this module from admin . i was just checking what will happened if i click on delete button :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create it again using simple procedure -

1. Go to Extensions > Modules > Featured (click Edit button at the
   right).
2. Enter Module Name as home-page-featured (put any name to recognize
   it).
3. Add feature products to it.
4. Make Status as Enabled
5. You should see something like this now. Add suitable limit,width,height.:[image]
6. Click Save button.
7. Now Go to Design > Layouts and edit **Home** layout (for version less than 2.1.x - go to System > Design > Layouts)
8. Click on add module button at right corner.
9. Choose home-page-featured for "**Module**" , select suitable **Position** and **Sort Order**. And Save it.

You will get to see featured module on home page.